# Kafka-docker container scaling failed for wurstmeister with error as "advertised listeners are already registered by broker 1001"

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

Single Kafka-docker broker instance is working fine with the downloaded image for wurstmeister.
Execution of below command result displayed as done on cmd prompt:

```
docker-compose scale kafka=2
WARNING: The scale command is deprecated. Use the up command with the --scale flag instead.
Starting mskafka_kafka_1 ... done
Creating mskafka_kafka_2 ... done
```

Although, the state of the container is Exit 1

```
docker-compose ps
The system cannot find the path specified.
       Name                      Command               State                          Ports
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
mskafka_apache_1      /bin/sh -c apache2ctl -D F ...   Up       0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp
mskafka_kafka_1       start-kafka.sh                   Up       0.0.0.0:9092->9093/tcp
mskafka_kafka_2       start-kafka.sh                   Exit 1
mskafka_postgres_1    docker-entrypoint.sh postgres    Up       5432/tcp
mskafka_zookeeper_1   /bin/sh -c /usr/sbin/sshd  ...   Up       0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp, 22/tcp, 2888/tcp, 3888/tcp
```

*`Configuration file : docker-compose.yml`*

```
kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka:2.11-2.0.0
    links:
     - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka
     # KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "order:5:1"
    ports:
     - "9092"
```

Container logs shows below stack trace:

```
[2018-12-27 11:12:42,035] INFO [LogDirFailureHandler]: Starting (kafka.server.ReplicaManager$LogDirFailureHandler)
[2018-12-27 11:12:42,056] ERROR [KafkaServer id=1002] Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Configured end points kafka:9092 in advertised listeners are already registered by broker 1001
        at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer$$anonfun$createBrokerInfo$2.apply(KafkaServer.scala:384)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer$$anonfun$createBrokerInfo$2.apply(KafkaServer.scala:382)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.createBrokerInfo(KafkaServer.scala:382)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:256)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:38)
        at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:75)
        at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
[2018-12-27 11:12:42,065] INFO [KafkaServer id=1002] shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

Environment Details:
1. OS - Windows 10
2. Docker kafka image : wurstmeister/kafka:2.11-2.0.0

Is there any configuration changes missing?

Answer (score 8):

You cannot scale a Kafka broker like it's just some web-app or API.

At least these properties need to be unique for each broker

- `KAFKA_BROKER_ID` (this is already handled for you)
- `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME` and `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT` to know where on the network that broker exists (these are deprecated, and the advertised listeners config should be used instead)
- `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS` is how clients know how to reach a specific broker; if this is allowed to be the same for multiple brokers, then only one of them would ever get any producer/consumer requests. The `HOSTNAME_COMMAND` can be used to set this, but you'll have to do something special for the ports

Note that the default replication factors of internal topics is only 1, and scaling from 1 to 3 brokers will not change this

If you look in the wurstmeister (and confluentinc/cp-docker-images) repos, they have multi-broker compose files, or you can look into using Strimzi / Bitnami Kubernetes operators for Kafka

Answer (score 4):

Following configuration in docker-compose.yaml file have resolved the error and kafka on single node is able to scale with the command

```
docker-compose scale kafka=3
```

> docker-compose.yaml :

```
kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka:2.11-2.0.0
    links:
     - zookeeper
    environment:
      HOSTNAME_COMMAND: "docker info | grep ^Name: | cut -d' ' -f 2" # Normal instances
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://_{HOSTNAME_COMMAND}:9094
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://:9094
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "order:5:2"
```

**Docker Containers:**

```
    docker ps
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                           COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                NAMES
    428142871bb0        wurstmeister/kafka:2.11-2.0.0   "start-kafka.sh"         18 minutes ago      Up 18 minutes                                                            mskafka_kafka_3
    def308e0b782        wurstmeister/kafka:2.11-2.0.0   "start-kafka.sh"         18 minutes ago      Up 18 minutes                                                            mskafka_kafka_2
    b72feb27804d        wurstmeister/kafka:2.11-2.0.0   "start-kafka.sh"         25 minutes ago      Up 25 minutes                                                            mskafka_kafka_1
    49e8cf39fee6        wurstmeister/zookeeper:3.4.6    "/bin/sh -c '/usr/sb…"   25 minutes ago      Up 25 minutes       22/tcp, 2888/tcp, 3888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp   mskafka_zookeeper_1
```